# Pagination error in custom taxonomy template

Tags: php, pagination, taxonomy

I created a custom post type called "library", with its "documentation" taxonomy; The problem occurs in the pagination of the taxonomy template (taxonomy-documentation.php).
I have determined a number of "18" posts per page, for the number of posts there should be "7" pages, but I list "16" pages, the pages from "8" to "16" are empty.
The url of archive for the taxonomy is: [Documentation Archive](http://www.cyberdocentes.com/documentation/documentos/)

The template loop is as follows:

```
        <?php 
        $term = $wp_query->queried_object;
        $getterm = $term->slug; // get current slug (E.g. winter2015)
        $args = (array(
        'post_type' => 'library',
        'showposts' => 18,
        'paged'=>$paged, 
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(                     
                'taxonomy' => 'documentation',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $getterm 
                ),
            ),
        ) );  

        $query = new wp_query( $args );
        if ( $query -> have_posts() ) : while ( $query -> have_posts() ) : $query -> the_post(); ?>
            <?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                    <?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'download_image', true ) ) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php get_the_title(); ?>">
                            <?php 
                            $postID = $post->ID;
                            $imageURI = get_post_meta($postID, 'download_image', true);
                            $attachmentID = pn_get_attachment_id_from_url ($imageURI);
                            $imagearray = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachmentID, 'full');
                            $imageURI = $imagearray[0];
                            $thumbarray = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachmentID, 'library-thumbnail');
                            $thumb_imageURI = $thumbarray[0];
                             echo "<img class='document-thumbnail' src='". $thumb_imageURI . "' alt='". get_the_title() ."' />";
                             ?>
                        </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <a class="document-title" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 40, '...'); ?></a><br />
                    <span><?php echo __('Published by', 'cyberdocentes'); ?> <a class="author-link" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' ) ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></span>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; rewind_posts(); ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="pagination">
                <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/pagenavi.php'); if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } else { ?>
                <div class="navigation">
                    <div class="alignleft">
                        <?php next_posts_link(__('Next posts','cyberdocentes')); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="alignright">
                        <?php previous_posts_link(__('Previous posts','cyberdocentes')); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php flush(); ?>
```

Comment: Solved pagination

Answer (score 1):

Solved code:

```
        <div class="documents-list">
            <?php
            $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'documentation' ) );
            global $wp_query;
            query_posts( array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'posts_per_page' => 18 ) ) );
            if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

//CODE OF THE ARTICLES HERE

            <?php endwhile; rewind_posts(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div id="pagination">
                    <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/pagenavi.php'); if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } else { ?>
                    <div class="navigation">
                        <div class="alignleft">
                            <?php next_posts_link(__('Next posts','cyberdocentes')); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alignright">
                            <?php previous_posts_link(__('Previous posts','cyberdocentes')); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php flush(); ?>
        </div>
```